# Publishing a site on the web

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a website. How do I publish it on the web so that it can be accessible from anywhere?

Comment: Just because somebody isn't able to communicate clearly doesn't mean you can pick on him.

Comment: The basic requirement to publish you own website is hosting space. You you own any hosting space?

Comment: No i dont own any hosting space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To publish your website, like build, you need to select publish the web site under the build tab or you can simply right click on the project name and select the publish web site option to publish the wesite from Solution Explorer.

Now, you will see a popup window. You can change the path to the precompiled website, otherwise it will be created at the default location.

You can select other options for your precompiled website by check boxes.

1. Allow this precompiled site to be updatable.
2. Use fixed naming and single page assemblies.
3. Enable strong naming on precompiled assemblies.

Simply click OK to publish your website.

I hope this helps you. If you are getting any error again, tell me about the error in detail.

Comment: I am getting the error:
A path to a key file is required.

where can I find that key file?

Answer (score 1):

Check some of these articles. They might be helpful if you want to host your website on the web:

- http://www.allaboutyourownwebsite.com/
- http://www.quackit.com/create-a-website/
- http://www.thesitewizard.com/gettingstarted/startwebsite.shtml

You can also start your own blog for free with some of the services like Blogger.com or wordpress etc. Google about blogging if you want to start a blog. The difference between a blog and a website is a blog is somebody else's domain. It's like putting your content on their site so others can view it. It'll remain your blog but it'll but hosted by them as they're doing it for free.
Creating your own website means you'll have to pay some annual subscription for your domain like (Mynewwebsite.com etc.) and you'll have to manage it on your own.

Comment: This is not really related to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than publishing you should use the web deployment project. Download the web deployment project from the link below.

http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=0aa30ae8-c73b-4bdd-bb1b-fe697256c459&displaylang=en

After downloading install it at your PC. Restart your Visual Studio. Open the project and right click on `Project` and click "Add web deployment Project". Give the project a path and build. You can find the deployable project at the path given by the web deployment project.